# How to use iOS 10 UserNotifications framework in xcode 7.3.1 swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to import user notifications of iOS 10 in Xcode 7.x with swift 2.x version?

Comment: Have u implemented UserNotifications for Xcode 7.3.1 ? even i want to use.

Comment: No, I had to convert my complete code to swift 3 using Xcode 8. It was painful

Answer (score 1):

`UserNotifications.framework` is available from iOS 10 and later. That is why we need Xcode 8 and later.

Comment: yes am installed xcode 8 and i try to convert my code to swift 3.0 but its not  converting perfectly. its  showing error in third party frame work,   mainly Alamofire showing lots of issue. Please any one help to fix it

Comment: Yeah, you have to use the latest versions of third-party libraries. Some of them don't even have swift 3 version, so you'll have to look for alternatives.