# voip push notification doesn't work on ios 10 when lock screen

Tags: notifications, ios10, voip, pushkit

I am using PushKit for sending voip push notification to my APP.
It works fine for iOS 9 and below.

But recently I was reported that the user unable to receive notifications when their phone in lock screen mode (on iOS 10).

I did few tests on it, on iOS 9, no matter if the screen was locked, all notification were received. On the other hand, on iOS 10, when a notification came, the screen was lighten up, but no other information, no sounds, no notification banner. That is, if the phone in lock screen mode, in your pocket, you were never be notified when a call is coming.

Is anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Are you scheduling local notification once you get pushki payload?

Comment: yes, might be related to UILocalNotification was deprecated on iOS 10. But when the screen was not locked, the local notification works fine

Comment: Try integrating userNotification.framework for ios 10 conditional.

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution. But for now, we have to keep old Xcode 7+ for development, may I use userNotification framework inside Xcode 7?

Comment: wi have same problem ... how to solve ?

Comment: @Deepesh have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using uilocalnotification in Xcode 8, then it is deprecated. This is May be reason of functionality not working properly.

Try integrating usernotification.framework. It will available with Xcode 8.

Moving from Xcode 7 to 8. If you have swift programming language. Then you need to convert code in swift 3. Most of Xcode will convert, may be rest of you need to rewrite.

Some reference
[How to use iOS 10 UserNotifications framework in xcode 7.3.1 swift 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960758/how-to-use-ios-10-usernotifications-framework-in-xcode-7-3-1-swift-2-2)

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification